# unable to add column with dplyr mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I currently have this data frame

```
    dat = data.frame(time= c("Q1","Q2","Q3"), 
                     measure1 = c(1,2,9   ),
                     measure2 = c(4,5,6   ))
    dat2 = dat %>% gather(key= Metric, value = Value, c(measure1, measure2)) %>% group_by(Metric, time)
dat2 = as.data.frame(dat2)

time   Metric Value
1   Q1 measure1     1
2   Q2 measure1     2
3   Q3 measure1     9
4   Q1 measure2     4
5   Q2 measure2     5
6   Q3 measure2     6
```

I can add this "test" column like this

```
dat2$test=  ifelse(  dat2$Metric =="measure1" &  dat2$Value >   dat2$Value[ dat2$Metric=="measure2"] ,1,
                               ifelse(  dat2$Metric == "measure2" &   dat2$Value >  dat2$Value[ dat2$Metric=="measure1"] ,1,-1)
                               ) #end ifelse

 time   Metric Value test
1   Q1 measure1     1   -1
2   Q2 measure1     2   -1
3   Q3 measure1     9    1
4   Q1 measure2     4    1
5   Q2 measure2     5    1
6   Q3 measure2     6   -1
```

BUT I would like to use dplyr and mutate  like this

```
dat = data.frame(time= c("Q1","Q2","Q3"), 
                 measure1 = c(1,2,9   ),
                 measure2 = c(4,5,6   ))
dat %>% gather(key= Metric, value = Value, c(measure1, measure2)) %>% group_by(Metric, time) %>%
     mutate(test= ifelse( Metric =="measure1" &  Value > Value[Metric=="measure2"] ,1,
                               ifelse( Metric =="measure2" &  Value > Value[Metric=="measure1"] ,1,-1)
                               ) #end ifelse
                        )#end mutate
dat2 = as.data.frame(dat2)
dat2
```

but the "test" column is all NA

```
 time   Metric Value test
1   Q1 measure1     1   NA
2   Q2 measure1     2   NA
3   Q3 measure1     9   NA
4   Q1 measure2     4   NA
5   Q2 measure2     5   NA
6   Q3 measure2     6   NA
```

why can't you use mutate to add the column? does it have something to do with using as.data.frame and adding it manually...mutate doesn't recognize the column name?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that when you group by `Metric`, for groups where `Metric` is `measure1`, `Metric == "measure2"` will always return FALSE, and `Value[FALSE] == numeric(0)`, zero length objects are transformed to NA after the `mutate`:

```
dat %>% 
        gather(key= Metric, value = Value, c(measure1, measure2)) %>% 
        group_by(time) %>%        # <<<<<<<<<<<< here
        mutate(test= ifelse(Metric =="measure1" & Value > Value[Metric=="measure2"] ,1,
                            ifelse(Metric =="measure2" & Value > Value[Metric=="measure1"],1,-1)
                            ) #end ifelse
              )

# Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
# Groups: time [3]

#     time   Metric Value  test
#   <fctr>    <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     Q1 measure1     1    -1
# 2     Q2 measure1     2    -1
# 3     Q3 measure1     9     1
# 4     Q1 measure2     4     1
# 5     Q2 measure2     5     1
# 6     Q3 measure2     6    -1
```

You can see more clearly what is happening when you group by Metric with this example:

```
dat %>% 
        gather(key= Metric, value = Value, c(measure1, measure2)) %>% 
        group_by(Metric, time) %>%
        mutate(test= Value[Metric == "measure2"])

# Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
# Groups: Metric, time [6]

#     time   Metric Value  test
#   <fctr>    <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     Q1 measure1     1    NA
# 2     Q2 measure1     2    NA
# 3     Q3 measure1     9    NA
# 4     Q1 measure2     4     4
# 5     Q2 measure2     5     5
# 6     Q3 measure2     6     6
```